# Run a shell script on first boot

Tags: boot, script

I want to make a script that runs on boot, as I'm making a PowerShell script to install the Raspberry Pi OS. It needs to install some things on boot. How do I make a script to run on first boot and then automatically destroy itself, just like `wpa_supplicant.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer: use [Raspberian Firstboot](https://github.com/nmcclain/raspberian-firstboot/tree/master).